# API dataflow google: workflow could not be created error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-dataflow

I try to access a REST API via Postman or SOAPUI and I received "PERMISSION_DENIED" Code "403 forbbiden", but when I test the same method in Google APIs Explorer I receive the code "200 OK"

I tested this method "Services > Dataflow API v1b3 > dataflow.projects.templates.create"; here is the link in the API Explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=es#p/dataflow/v1b3/dataflow.projects.templates.create

When I test this method on this Page I received 200 OK, but when I try to test the same method on SOAPUI, Postman and with other methods I received the next message:

```
The workflow could not be created. Causes: (947cb6fd5273ed12): Unable
to get machine type information for machine type n1-standard-1 in zone
us-central1-f because of insufficient permissions. Please refer to
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/access-control#creating_jobs` and
make sure you have sufficient permissions."
```

[google api explorer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX7kT.png)
[google api explorer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ1oV.png)

So, I checked the roles for the users permissions on IAM and assigned Owner to all users. But I receive the same error.

For example, if I request the following using APIs Explorer:

POST https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{porjectid}/templates

```
{
 "jobName": "job_2019-07-22_14:15:24",
 "parameters": {
  "inputLocations": input location,
  "outputLocations": output location
 },
 "environment": {
  "tempLocation": temp location
  "zone": "us-central1-f"
 },
 "gcsPath": path correct
}
```

I receive:

200

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  225
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 22 Jul 2019 22:53:24 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

```
{
 "id": "2019-07-22_15_53_22-5610507684062605467",
 "projectId": project id,
 "name": "job_2019-07-22_14:15:24",
 "type": "JOB_TYPE_BATCH",
 "currentStateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
 "createTime": "2019-07-22T22:53:24.505713Z",
 "location": "us-central1",
 "startTime": "2019-07-22T22:53:24.505713Z"
}
```

(Something was deleted intentionally).

When I try to test on postman (for example) I receive:

[postman 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oCWI.png)
[postman 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG8An.png)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "(9f57a17249c91ca0): The workflow could not be created. Causes: (9f57a17249c9127d): Unable to get machine type information for machine type n1-standard-1 in zone us-central1-f because of insufficient permissions. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/access-control#creating_jobs and make sure you have sufficient permissions.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this must have something to do with attaching credentials which Google's API explorer does automatically, but SOAPUI and Postman do not.

Do you have a use case you could describe? This API is generally called by the dataflow client libraries when you create a pipeline and ask it to create a template. Its quite difficult to construct the pipeline object in the request manually. So I wouldn't advise calling this API on your own.

Comment: You may be able to authenticate with oauth by creating client credentials and attaching them to the request in the other tools. This example shows how to do this in a python program. The same approach may work with Postman or SOAPUI
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user